# Google Maps API (JS) Create a route using PlaceId in waypoints

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, direction

The route create only if I use LatLng or String params but I need create it by PlaceId but it doesn't work

example:

```
directionsService.route({
        origin: {'placeId': 'ChIJc1lGdwfP20YR3lGOMZD-GTM'},
        destination: {'placeId': 'ChIJdTGhqsbP20YR6DZ2QMPnJk0'},
        waypoints: [{stopover: true, location: new google.maps.Place('ChIJRVj1dgPP20YRBWB4A_sUx_Q')}],
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just need to pass the [`google.maps.Place`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Place) object as the waypoint location.
For example:

```
directionsService.route({
    origin: { placeId: "ChIJc1lGdwfP20YR3lGOMZD-GTM" },
    destination: { placeId: "ChIJdTGhqsbP20YR6DZ2QMPnJk0" },
    waypoints: [{ stopover: true, location: { placeId: "ChIJRVj1dgPP20YRBWB4A_sUx_Q" } }],
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
}
```

> **location** specifies the location of the waypoint, as a LatLng, as a
>   google.maps.Place object or as a String which will be geocoded.

[Google Maps - Direction Services Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests)

[Here's the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswatts91/5u52ac5y/)

Answer (score 4):

I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.Place is not a constructor` on this line:

```
waypoints: [{stopover: true, location: new google.maps.Place('ChIJRVj1dgPP20YRBWB4A_sUx_Q')}],
```

You need to specify that `location` the same way you do with the `origin` and `destination` placeIds:

```
waypoints: [{
  stopover: true,
  location: {'placeId':"ChIJRVj1dgPP20YRBWB4A_sUx_Q"}
}],
```

Description in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Place):

> **Google.maps.Place object specification**
>
> **placeId** | Type:  string
>   The place ID of the place (such as a business or point of interest). The place ID is a unique identifier of a place in the Google Maps database. Note that the placeId is the most accurate way of identifying a place. If possible, you should specify the placeId rather than a placeQuery. A place ID can be retrieved from any request to the Places API, such as a TextSearch. Place IDs can also be retrieved from requests to the Geocoding API. For more information, see the [overview of place IDs](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/neopxfhs/2/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map
  });
  directionsService.route({
    origin: {
      'placeId': 'ChIJc1lGdwfP20YR3lGOMZD-GTM'
    },
    destination: {
      'placeId': 'ChIJdTGhqsbP20YR6DZ2QMPnJk0'
    },
    waypoints: [{
      stopover: true,
      location: {
        'placeId': "ChIJRVj1dgPP20YRBWB4A_sUx_Q"
      }
    }],
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```